# Flexislider Thumbnails Click Issue - Intermediate Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, flexslider

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/pb0wxqrf/1/)**

Steps : click 1-3 again and again and then click on active thumnail twice then next thumnail click wont work.

I have implemented Flexi Slider with Thumbnails, Its working fine, but sometimes The Thumbnails are not clickable. Not sure where Iam going Wrong.

```
/* New Slider */
    $('.sliderNew #carousel').flexslider({
        animation       : "slide",
        controlNav      : true,
        animationLoop   : true,
        slideshow       : true,
        itemWidth       : 140,
        itemMargin      : 5,
        minItems        : 1,
        asNavFor        : '.sliderNew #slider',
        reverse         : false
    });

    $('.sliderNew #slider').flexslider({
        animation       : "slide",
        controlNav      : false,
        animationLoop   : true,
        slideshow       : true,
        reverse         : false,        
        sync            : ".sliderNew #carousel",
        start: function( slider ) {
            $('.sliderNew #carousel .slides li').on('click',function(event){
                //alert('asd')
                $('.sliderNew #slider').flexslider("play");
            });
        }       
    });
    /* New Slider */
```

Appreciate your help..

Thanks..

Comment: It would help if your demo page wasn't password-protected, so that people could see it! The first thing I would do is see if some other element is overlaying the thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some digging and found that this is probably due to a bug in the FlexSlider version you're using (version 2.1). In the Github updates (unfortunately they only go back to version 2.2) I did read something about "click handler updates", so I guess you've been so unfortunate to stumble upon an old bug. I've tracked it back [to this update on GitHub](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/commit/0ef4a104e1e67424ded9fb201b7d6dd2c56ec3a8), but that's more or less a guess.

On the bright side, they've fixed the bug. I've updated the JSFiddle to use the new version of FlexSlider:
http://jsfiddle.net/ennesht2/

You probably also want to check what you're doing with your CSS/positioning, because the demo looks like it's falling apart in Safari/Chrome (OSX). I've done one quick fix in your CSS to make the navigation element appear in this new version (uncommented the `height:0`), but you'll also want to update your CSS to use FlexSlider's version 2.3 one.

```
 .sliderNew #carousel .flex-viewport {
     border :none;
     //height:0;
     display:inline-block;
     width:100%;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, let me integrate this with the site. will keep u posted. Thanks Again

Comment: Hi Eric, turning slideshow & AnimationLoop , Both to True, Active Class is not Working now :-(

Comment: Updated : Turning both values to TRUE Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/sq4bmeqs/6/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since you are already using IDs to grab your DOM elements, you can simply use `$('#slider')` instead of `$('.sliderNew #slider')`. The same logic goes for the carousel element :)

I think you may wish to set the click handler on the `img` element, rather than its parent (the `li` element). So perhaps:

```
start: function( slider ) {
        $('#carousel .slides li img').on('click',function(event){
            $('#slider').flexslider("play");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch on this one, I think that whenever your slide is running, it's coming over your thumbs, this happened once in a project I participated in.

The following is not a good practice of z-index but it should help you find out if this is the problem.

Add the following to your css to test the theory:

```
#carousel .slides li{
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link or can you assemble the slider in a fiddle?